# Finding duplicate lines in a CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to use Powershell to search a csv file and output a list of duplicate lines in a csv file. I can accomplish this pretty easily in bash with the following:

```
uniq -d myfile.csv > list.csv
```

In Powershell I can output a list of unique lines but how do I modify `Get-Unique` to display only the duplicate lines like I did in bash?

```
Get-Content c:\file\myfile.csv | Get-Unique | Set-Content c:\file\list1.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit weird to use the unique tool to get the duplicates. How about:

```
gc .\test.csv | group -NoElement |? Count -gt 1 | select -expand name
```

This groups the lines by how many there are, identifies the ones with duplicates, and outputs them. e.g. if:

```
test.csv contains:

a,b,c
d,e,f
a,b,c
z,z,z

gc test.csv | group

Count Name                      Group                                                                    
----- ----                      -----                                                                    
    2 a,b,c                     {a,b,c, a,b,c}                                                           
    1 d,e,f                     {d,e,f}                                                                  
    1 z,z,z                     {z,z,z}                                                                  
    1                           {}
```

and `-NoElement` stops it building the group contents, redundant in this case.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.